# How to remove subjects with missing yearly observations in R?

Tags: r, panel-data

```
     num Name  year   age       X 
1      1   A   2011    68  116292
2      1   A   2012    69   46132
3      1   A   2013    70    7042
4      1   A   2014    71 -100425
5      1   A   2015    72    6493
6      2   B   2011    20   -8484
7      3   C   2015    23 -120836
8      4   D   2011     3  -26523
9      4   D   2012     4    9923
10     4   D   2013     5   82432
```

I have the data which is represented by various subjects in 5 years. I need to remove all the subjects, which are missing any of years from 2011 to 2015. How can I accomplish it, so in given data only subject A is left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check which names have the right number of entries.

```
## Reproduce your data
df = read.table(text="     num Name  year   age       X 
1      1   A   2011    68  116292
2      1   A   2012    69   46132
3      1   A   2013    70    7042
4      1   A   2014    71 -100425
5      1   A   2015    72    6493
6      2   B   2011    20   -8484
7      3   C   2015    23 -120836
8      4   D   2011     3  -26523
9      4   D   2012     4    9923
10     4   D   2013     5   82432",
header=TRUE)

Tab = table(df$Name)
Keepers = names(Tab)[which(Tab == 5)]
df[df$Name %in% Keepers,]
  num Name year age       X
1   1    A 2011  68  116292
2   1    A 2012  69   46132
3   1    A 2013  70    7042
4   1    A 2014  71 -100425
5   1    A 2015  72    6493
```

Comment: Did not know you could do that with `text` in `read.table`, cool +1 :)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, but I had to use ID instead of actual names, which gave an error of not being a vector.

Answer (score 2):

**Using data.table:**

A `data.table` solution might look something like this:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df)
dt[, keep := identical(unique(year), 2011:2015), by = Name ][keep == T, ][,keep := NULL]
#   num Name year age       X
#1:   1    A 2011  68  116292
#2:   1    A 2012  69   46132
#3:   1    A 2013  70    7042
#4:   1    A 2014  71 -100425
#5:   1    A 2015  72    6493
```

This is more strict in that it requires that the unique years be exactly equal to 2011:2015. If there is a 2016, for example that person would be excluded.

---

A less restrictive solution would be to check that `2011:2015` is in your unique years. This should work:

```
dt[, keep := all(2011:2015 %in% unique(year)), by = Name ][keep == T, ][,keep := NULL]
```

Thus, if for example, `A` had a 2016 year and a 2010 year it would still keep all of A. But if anyone is missing a year in `2011:2015` this would exclude them.

---

**Using base R & aggregate:**

Same option, but using `aggregate` from base R:

```
agg <- aggregate(df$year, by = list(df$Name), FUN = function(x) all(2011:2015 %in% unique(x)))
df[df$Name %in% agg[agg$x == T, 1] ,]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have tried all three ways. For some reason, the first one drops all observations. The second approach (even though I only have 2011:2015, still tried it) gave expected result, but only after I used id number instead of name. Could it be a problem with names? Each name is at 3 words long, contains only english characters.

Comment: It could be an issue with the names, but it's hard to say without seeing your actual data. You need to group by whatever the unqiue person is in your dataset

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly more straightforward `tidyverse` solution.
First, expand the dataframe to include all combinations of Name + year:

```
df %>% complete(Name, year)

    # A tibble: 20 x 5
     Name  year   num   age       X
   <fctr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
 1      A  2011     1    68  116292
 2      A  2012     1    69   46132
 3      A  2013     1    70    7042
 4      A  2014     1    71 -100425
 5      A  2015     1    72    6493
 6      B  2011     2    20   -8484
 7      B  2012    NA    NA      NA
 8      B  2013    NA    NA      NA
 9      B  2014    NA    NA      NA
10      B  2015    NA    NA      NA
...
```

Then extend the pipe to group by "Name", and filter to keep only those with 0 NA values:

```
df %>% complete(Name, year) %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(sum(is.na(age)) == 0)

# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   Name [1]
    Name  year   num   age       X
  <fctr> <int> <int> <int>   <int>
1      A  2011     1    68  116292
2      A  2012     1    69   46132
3      A  2013     1    70    7042
4      A  2014     1    71 -100425
5      A  2015     1    72    6493
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a somewhat different approach using `tidyverse` packages:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read.table(text = "     num Name  year   age       X 
1      1   A   2011    68  116292
2      1   A   2012    69   46132
3      1   A   2013    70    7042
4      1   A   2014    71 -100425
5      1   A   2015    72    6493
6      2   B   2011    20   -8484
7      3   C   2015    23 -120836
8      4   D   2011     3  -26523
9      4   D   2012     4    9923
10     4   D   2013     5   82432")

df2 <- spread(data = df, key = Name, value = year)
x <- colSums(df2[, 4:7], na.rm = TRUE) > 10000
df3 <- select(df2, num, age, X, c(4:7)[x])
df4 <- na.omit(df3)
```

All steps can of course be constructed as one single pipe with the `%>%` operator.